# Why do electrocatalysts based on polyoxometalates and carbon materials have a weaker activity/performance in acidic media?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, catalysis

I am testing now some doped N and S doped carbon nanomaterials alone and immobilized in POM for the purpose of developing a nanocomposite that can serve as an electrocatalyst for energy-related reactions in order to replace Pt.

The purpose in this work is for the reaction to proceed in 1 step, which means to have a 4 electron transfer.

In KOH 0.1 M they are giving better results (3.0 - 3.6 e), while in H2SO4 0.1 M the number of transferred electrons goes down to 1.5-2.

I was wondering what might be the specific reason of the acidic media (hydrogen cations) to lead to this ?

Thank you!